# how to use navigation.replace in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use this in my code:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
navigation.replace('AllFriends')
```

But I keep getting an error that:

```
Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.
```

I also tried using this

```
const navigation =  useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<{route: {} }>>()
navigation.replace('route');
```

as suggested here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8256

but this gives me an error on replace that expected 2 arguments but got only 1...

I am using  "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",

Answer (score 12):

The replace method is only available to screens within StackNavigators. We need a way to explicitly type that the screen is such.

When you instantiate your StackNavigator, you have the ability to pass in a type that defines your Routes with the parameters they expect to receive:

```
export type StackParams = {
   MyRoute: undefined;
   AnotherRoute: {
      id: number
   }
}

createStackNavigator<StackParams>();
```

Then in the screen you pass that param list to `StackNavigationProp`

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack/';
import { StackParams} form 'your/routes';

const navigation =  useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<StackParams>>()
navigation.replace('route');
```

Doing this affirms that this is a Stack screen and provides a list of routes that you can navigate to:

```
replace('AnotherRoute') //success!
replace('FakeRoute') //error, this was not defined in our RouteParams
```

Comment: Found your answer really helpful. thank you for that!

Comment: I was missing the `@react-navigation/stack` package, which is why the solution on the GitHub bug report did not work. Thanks for this elaborate answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
const navigation =  useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<{route: {} }>>()
navigation.replace('route');
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated here : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7820#issuecomment-689646876

The simplest way is this one :

```js
const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

for those on react native and still using class components these days and have the standard NavigatorParamList setup

```
export type NavigatorParamList = {
 ...
}

export type ScreenProps = NavigationProp<NavigatorParamList>

export type ScreenComponentProps<T extends keyof NavigatorParamList> = {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<NavigatorParamList, T> // changed from navigation: NavigationProp<NavigatorParamList, T>
  route: RouteProp<NavigatorParamList, T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { ParamListBase, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';


const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this helps solving the question.

Comment: Is this different from the other answers? If yes, please elaborate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!